# NoMethodError: undefined method `set_password' for Service (call 'Service.connection' to establish a connection):Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

Why am I getting this error?

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `set_password' for Service (call 'Service.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

Here is my model(named Service)

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
    def set_password
        self.password = p SecureRandom.base64(5)
        self.save
    end
end
```

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must be calling the method on the classclass (e.g Service.set_password) instead of an instance (e.g. Service.new.set_password or Service.first.set_password).

Read up on the difference between class and instance methods:

http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/writing_classes/methods.html